# The import javax.servlet http can't be resolved

Tags: servlets

![Eclipse Screen Shot the file structure and errors are lie in the image, if there is any improper file structure please let me know ][1]The Error shows like in the following image,Hello Everyone i am a servlet beginer , i have a problem with the following servlet code, could any one help to fix it.it shows **javax.servlet.http cannot be resolved** how to fix this issues?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.second.po.User;
import com.second.serivce.UserService;

public class regServlet extends HttpServlet {
//UserDao userDao=new UserDao();//模式一直接通过UserDao访问数据库
private UserService userService=new UserService();//通过类之间的组合关系将其组合




    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String uname =request.getParameter("uname").trim();
    String pwd =request.getParameter("pwd").trim();
    String email =request.getParameter("email").trim();
    String phone =request.getParameter("phone").trim();
    String address =request.getParameter("address").trim();
    int age =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
    int gender =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("gender"));
    int degree =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("degree"));

    java.sql.Date joinTime=new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());


    User user=new User("老高","1234","1808029435@qq.com",18,"13378052446","北京",0,1,joinTime);
    userService.register(user);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("reg_ok.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request,response);

}


}
```

Comment: add the servlet-api to your classpath

Comment: Most IDEs will support adding it, by marking it as "unrecognized" but when you put the cursor on the error it will let you include it in your project or look for it over the web (IntelliJ has such an option).

Comment: Thanks alex, could you explain were to download it.

Comment: There  are various versions which one i have to download?

Comment: Thanks Alex, its done i tool that from tomcat lib, and added that in a class path, and its done.hats off  :-)

Comment: If you have a solution, you can write about it in the answer box provided. This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question.